# breaking template code in to separate compilation units

Tags: c++, templates

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++03 application that uses template metaprogramming. The MPL can take a significant amount of time to compile (~15 minutes). I obviously don't want to incur this cost every time I make a minor change to some unrelated part of the code. So, I'd like break them in to separate object files.

For example:

```
// Foo.hpp
template< typename T >
inline boost::shared_ptr< Bar > Foo( const Data& d )
{
    /* MPL magic takes a long time to compile */
    switch( d.a )
    {
    case 0:
        return MPLMagic::Create< ZeroTraits, T >( d.b, d.c  );
    case 1:
        return MPLMagic::Create< OneTraits, T >( d.b, d.c );
    default:
        return MPLMagic::Create< DefaultTraits, T >( d.b, d.c );
    }
}

// Bob.hpp
#include "Foo.hpp"
template< typename X, typename Y >
inline void BobFunc()
{
    Data d = /* Bob's data */;
    boost::shard_ptr< Bar > created = Foo< BobTraits >( d );
    // do bob stuff
}

// Charlie.hpp
#include "Foo.hpp"
template< typename X, typename Y >
inline void CharlieFunc()
{
    Data d = /* Charlie's data */;
    boost::shard_ptr< Bar > created = Foo< CharlieTraits >( d );
    // do charlie stuff
}
```

How can I separate these header files out such that changes to Charlie don't incur a recompile of Bob and change to some unrelated section don't require recompiling them both?

Comment: Well, since `BobFunc` and `CharlieFunc` are not templates, not having their definitions in the header should help a lot.

Comment: Have you tried using precompiled header for `Foo.hpp`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. would actually help compiling also, seeing they're not `inline` & all...

Comment: @All - my apologies. all of the code is templated and inlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption (from the code above) that you allow only a small subset of types to instantiate the template you can split the templates into a declaration the definition in a single translation unit where you explicitly instantiate the templates.

Additionally consider changing `Foo` to implement the `AbstractFactory` pattern where concrete factories register in a map of `int` -> `creator`, and that will allow you to split the compilation of `Foo` (probably the most expensive part) into multiple files, one for each particular trait. This allows extension of the framework without having to recompile all the template magic, and additionally will reduce the memory footprint of the compiler which might be one of the reasons that it takes so much to compile now.